# Change Name of Signature annotation In DevExpress Controls

Tags: devexpress

I'm creating a pdf file using the DevExpress Controls demo application from (https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPNetCore/Demo/Reporting/ReportDesigner/). I have multiple signature annotations and exporting a PDF file. My purpose is to send the PDF file to multiple people for signature purposes, but there they need to differentiate which location belongs to which person and apply their signatures to it.

To do that, I'm changing the name and tag of the signature annotations, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Exporting the PDF file

[image]

but when i'm reading the file's name using the Adobe Acrobat Reader, it's not showing the updated name but instead the default name.

The name of the signature annotation

[image]

How to change the name of the signature annotation?